# How to find a value in an array and unset by using PHP array functions?

Tags: php, arrays

I have participants form with multiple select option:

```html
<select name="userid[]" id="" multiple>
    <option value="1">xyz</option>
    <option value="2">xy1</option>
    <option value="3">1aw</option>
    <option value="4">abc</option>
</select>
```

I selected 3 users and saved to database with `$participents = implode(',', $_POST['userid']);` and database saved as `1,2,3`.

Now I want to remove a user from participant list by clicking remove button.

```php
$pid = $_POST['pid']; //participant form id
$id = $_POST['id'];   // user id i need to delete

$aa = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * from `participant_registrations` where id='$pid' ")  or
    die(mysqli_error($conn));

$bb = mysqli_fetch_assoc($aa);
$ss = implode(',', array($bb['participents']));
unset($ss[array_search($id, $ss)]);
mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE `participant_registrations` SET participents='$ss' WHERE id='$pid' ")  or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

But I'm getting error like:

> Warning: array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in C:\wamp64\www\bkjy\participantlist.php on line 17
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot unset string offsets in C:\wamp64\www\bkjy\participantlist.php on line 17

Help me where it went wrong.

Comment: Don't put comma-separated lists in SQL tables. Normalize your design.

Comment: You should be using `explode`, not `implode`.

Comment: `$ss = explode(',', $bb['participents']);`

Comment: if you have done normalised tables you wouldn't need to do string manipulations like `explode` in the ids to begin with

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `explode()` to split the string into an array. And then you have to use `implode()` to put it back into the table.

```
$ss = explode(',', $bb['participents']);
$index = array_search($id, $ss);
if ($index !== false) {
    array_splice($ss, $index, 1);
    $participents = implode(',', $ss);
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "UPDATE `participant_registrations` SET participents=? WHERE id=? ");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $participents, $pid);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
```

You should also use prepared statements instead of substituting variables into SQL, I've shown that change above.